# How to draw path like canvas in Android using OpenGL ES 2?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, android-canvas

I have tried Canvas in Android, and I can make sketch or path by moving my finger on the screen.
Now, I want to do the same thing using OpenGL 2.
I'm new to OpenGL programming but I have tried several method to draw a Line using GLES20.glDrawArray(...) and a Line Shape class
but still, this just make a straight line not like a free-form path i wanted just like when I use canvas.
and also, if i try to draw per line segment each time ACTION_MOVE, concurrent modification exception often happens since i store each Line segment in an ArrayList.
is there any helping API by OpenGL to achieve this?
if there's or there isn't, how can i make this?
Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to achieve this? If yes, could you please share your code? I am trying to do the same thing right now.

Comment: I have implemented everything else as per given in the answer and everything is working fine. However, now I don't know how to add points dynamically to the vertex and index buffer. Could you please help me do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to draw a consistent line along a path, then you're in fact trying to draw many short lines which are all connected to each other.

I think the most intuitive way of doing this, is adding each point on the path into an array of points, and then, maintaining a float buffer, where each 3 items describe a single point on the path (x,y,z). Then, for every point which is added to this vertex buffer, you should add two integers into an index buffer. If you're new to index buffers, the way it works (when you're working with lines), is it tells OpenGL which two vertexes are connected. For instance:

Say you have 3 points. Inside the Vertex buffer, you would have 9 floats - 3 points * 3 coordinates for each point. We would like the 1st point to be connected to the 2nd, and the 2nd point to be connected to the 3rd. We can do this by using an Index Buffer. In the index buffer, we will place 2 integers for every vertex connection. For connecting the 1st point to the 2nd, we will player 0 & 1 into the buffer. This says that the 1st 3 coordinates in the vertex buffer are connected to the 2nd 3 coordinates in the vertex buffer. Then, we will place 1 & 2 in the index buffer. This says that the 2nd 3 coordinates in the vertex buffer are connected to the 3rd 3 coordinates in the vertex buffer - and so on.

```
Vertex Buffer:
{
  0, 0, 0, // Index 0
  1, 1, 1, // Index 1
  2, 3, 4  // Index 2
}

Index Buffer:
{
  0, 1, // Connect Index 0 to Index 1
  1, 2  // Connect Index 1 to Index 2
}
```

You will need to call `glDrawElements` rather than `glDrawArrays`, but the idea is the same - you only need to maintain an additional buffer for the indexes, and make sure to always update both buffers each time you add a new point.

As for the concurrent modification exception - you need to be a bit careful here. If you add a point to the array while you're iterating over the array (for example, with a "for each" style loop), then this will happen. A good solution is to surround any interaction with the point array with a synchronize block, and use the array itself as a mutex:

```
Adding:
synchronized(myPointArray)
{
  myPointArray.add(newPoint);
}


Iterating:
synchronized(myPointArray)
{
  for (PointF point : myPointArray)
  {
    // do stuff with the point
  }
}
```

This should get you started.