# Finger paint using OpenGL ES. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I want to build a kind of paint app with opengl and I followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25021991/how-to-draw-path-like-canvas-in-android-using-opengl-es-2?answertab=active#tab-top) instruction.

However when I touch the screen multiple times I get the error message: "app has stopped." and the exception:

> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x7554d018 in tid 7210 (GLThread 379)

This is my code for touch events:

```
public void processTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();
            // In this method I update the vector and I set "longTouch" (boolean variable) to true
            addPoint(x, y); 
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            longTouch = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

The logic that I'm following is that when the user drags his finger on the screen in DrawFrame "longTouch" (boolean variable) is activated to true, then it's created or updated the vertex buffer and the index buffer and these it's sent to draw the lines with DrawElements.

```
if (longTouch){

        if (vertices.length >= 4){
            ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
            vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
            vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
            vertexBuffer.position(0);

            index = new short[vertices.length];

            for (short i = 0; i < index.length; i++){
                index[i] = i;
            }

            ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(index.length * 2);
            ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            indexBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();
            indexBuffer.put(index);
            indexBuffer.position(0);

            glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
            glDrawElements(GL_LINES, index.length, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);
        }

    }
```

I update and re-dimension the vector correctly, so I guess this is not the error. I guess the error is related to **threads** but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you are changing the size of an OpenGL buffer from your GUI thread, while OpenGL is constantly accessing the buffers from its own thread, causing the segment fault.

Make sure you only touch your buffers in the code executed by the OpenGL thread itself, never in another thread.

If you must access variables shared between threads, place the variables in a Java `synchronized` block.